# Creating new Django Object with newly created user

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm attempting to auto-load a bulk list of users into a Django application and I'm creating the users as follows...

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(
                username='testusername',
                password='testpassword',
                email='testemail',
                first_name='testfirstname',
                last_name='testlastname'
                )
new_user.save()
new_user_phone = Phone.objects.create(
                uid = new_user,
                number = 'phone_number',
                validated = True,
                text = True,
                voice = True,
                created_on = datetime.now(),
                validated_on = datetime.now()
                )
```

The User object is created successfully, but when the Phone object is attempting to be made it throws an error stating

> Cannot assign User: testusername, "Phone.uid" must be a "User" instance.

But when I check the type it's of 'User' type, and as stated above the User object is successfully created in the DB while the script stops before creating the phone.

Any direction on this error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: My phone model is below

```
class Phone(models.Model):
  number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  validated = models.BooleanField()
  text = models.BooleanField()
  voice = models.BooleanField()
  created_on = models.DateTimeField()
  uid = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING)
  validated_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Please show us the `Phone` model, specifically how `uid` is defined.

Comment: The original post has been edited to include the phone model. The User model is the defualt Django User model with no additions.

Comment: The error suggests that the `User` object you're trying to assign is different from the `User` object you've just created - even though you say it's just the default user model. Can you show us how you are importing the `User` class in both parts of your code?

Comment: @clf01 Which django version your using? Code look fine, only new_user.save() is not required because it create_user will return you object of User after saving it to db.

Answer (score 0):

solarissmoke was correct in saying my User object wasn't the default Django model being imported.

The models.py was autogenerated from an existing database and was defaulting to that User class. Once that class was removed from the models.py file, everything worked as it should.

Thanks!